# NHibernate: SaveOrUpdate by <natural-id>

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, many-to-one

Is there an easy way to make NH INSERT or UPDATE an entity depending on whether there is already an entity with same `<natural-id />`?

The entity is mapped to another (root) one using `<many-to-one cascade="save-update" />`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not automatically. You will have to read from the database to see if a record for that natural-id already exists and then determine if you need to do an insert or update. Which of course means that the cascade won't work.

I was looking for something similar in [How do I Insert or Update (or overwrite) a record using NHibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325990/how-do-i-insert-or-update-or-overwrite-a-record-using-nhibernate)

Comment: Another solution is to write sql-insert in such way that it actually does upsert. But I would prefer a way to hook into NHibernate and force it to generate the correct insert.